# Consulta SQL no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Eu quero executar esse sql1 e caso ele não me retorne nenhum resultado eu executo o sql2 e apresento ele, mas assim não está funcionando, quando o sql1 retorna resultado ele apresenta certo, mas quando não tem resultado, não é apresentado o resultado do sql2. Como devo fazer?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda. Vlw!!!

```
public function listaConciliar($id) {
            //Conectar ao banco;
            $this -> conectar();

            $sql1 = "SELECT id_tipo, id_empresa, id_acao, cod_empresa, empresa, data_inicial, data_final, usuario, descricao FROM empresa AS e INNER JOIN tipo AS t ON e.id_empresa = t.empresa_id_empresa INNER join acao AS a ON a.id_acao = t.acao_id_acao where id_empresa = ".$id." and id_acao = 1 ORDER BY id_tipo DESC LIMIT 1;";

            $resultadoEmpresaPeriodo = $this -> conexao -> query($sql1);

            if ($resultadoEmpresaPeriodo != NULL) {

                $empresa = new Empresa();
                while ($row = $resultadoEmpresaPeriodo -> fetch_assoc()) {              
                    $empresa -> setIdEmpresa($row['id_empresa']);
                    $empresa -> setCodEmpresa($row['cod_empresa']);
                    $empresa -> setEmpresa($row['empresa']);
                    $empresa -> setDataInicial($row['data_inicial']);
                    $empresa -> setDataFinal($row['data_final']);
                    $empresa -> setUsuario($row['usuario']);
                }

                $this -> desconectar();

                return $empresa;
            } else {

                $this -> conectar();

                //Executar sql;
                $sql2 = "SELECT id_empresa, cod_empresa, empresa FROM empresa WHERE id_empresa = ".$id." ORDER BY empresa LIMIT 1;";

                $resultado = $this -> conexao -> query($sql2);

                $empresa1 = new Empresa();
                while ($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()) {                
                    $empresa1 -> setIdEmpresa($row['id_empresa']);
                    $empresa1 -> setCodEmpresa($row['cod_empresa']);
                    $empresa1 -> setEmpresa($row['empresa']);
                }

                $this -> desconectar();

                return $empresa1;
            }

            /*$this -> desconectar();

            return $empresa;*/

        }
```

Comment: Tens a certeza que a empresa com o `$id` que passas a essa função existe? Provavelmente não, e ambas as queries retornam vazio por isso, e apenas funciona quando a primeira query tem resultados, porque de facto existe, assim como iria mostrar se corresse a 2a query, só não entra no `else`.

Comment: `var_dump($resultadoEmpresaPeriodo);` retorna o que?

Comment: Consegui resolver mudando a forma de conferir se o resultado é nulo ou não, executei as duas query e armazenei o resultado das duas depois faço um if pra conferir qual não tem valor:if ($empresa -> getDataInicial() != NULL) {
    
    $this -> desconectar();

    return $empresa;

   } elseif ($empresa -> getDataInicial() == NULL) {
    
    $this -> desconectar();

    return $empresa1;

   }

Comment: Se comparasse pelo número de linhas da consulta  tb daria certo.